# Android studio - voice recognition for alphabet

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, android-studio-3.0, voice-recognition

Im developing an voice recognition app for thesis that will recognize the letters of the alphabet. I manage to do speech to text reconition but I dont know how I'm gonna do it to recognize only letters and not words. like if I say "A" the app should display a picture of letter A. can you help me guys.
Below is an example code of my speech recognition app with the help of youtube and I do it by comparing the string "apple" to speech-to-text recognition.

```
final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

    final Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        textview.setText(bundle.getString("letterA"));
        if (textview.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("apple")){
            q="apple";
            Glide.with(Voice_view.this).load(R.drawable.apple).into(imageView);
            letter.setText("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the problem with recognizing A,B,C... letters of the alphabet has a couple of dimensions, first the small amount of audio data and second the tendency of some letters to sound similar. We can say "A" in a very short time, leading to very little audio data relative to that which is needed for accurate detection. "b,c,d,e,g..." all end in an "iy" sound so all we have to go on to separate them is a very short flash of audio at the beginning. Decoders are usually much happier with "A" because we tend to drag it out in enunciation.

In some recognition contexts you can gain much control if you have access to a context free grammar to narrow down what can be recognized as valid sentences. Online recognizers don't give you this option (as far as I know). Standalone recognizers such as Julius can use a Backus-Naur form of context free grammar so your chances of hitting single letters are much improved although not solved.